# What's the fastest way to earn Prisoner's Honey?

Tags: fallen-london

In Echo Bazaar, what's the fastest way to earn Prisoner's Honey, assuming you've maxed out all of your stats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're popular with the Bohemians you can cash-in your connections for Honey at the Shuttered Palace.

Other than that you occasionally get Honey from opportunity cards, and there are some lowish level stories in Spite (Rob a Honey den) and Veilgarden (Write about your Honey dreams), that will net you a small quantity at a time.

These are the only sources I've come across so far (D85/W87/P66/S54).

Comment: You can't Rob a Honey Den once you've outgrown that story in Spite (once you've maxed out your Shadowy). Good point about the Bohemians in the Shuttered Palace. I'll use that!

Comment: @Dan: Is it not possible to bring your Shadowy down enough with Ridiculous hats/Bottled oblivion/etc. ?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only knock 20 points off your Shadowy: 10 for a Ridiculous Hat, 5 for Bottled Oblivion, and 5 for Talkative Rattus Faber. My maxed out Shadowy is 110; 90 Shadowy is not low enough to rob the honey den.

Comment: @Dan: Fair enough

Comment: An update: The Talkative Rattus Faber now gives -25 to your stats, and the Ridiculous Hat now permanently abuses your stats. You can, conceivably, get down to 0 in every Quality if you're willing to go through enough hats.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply purchase Prisoner's Honey from Merrigans Exhange in the Echo Bazaar (in the Bazaar tab), for 4 pence each.

I have no idea whether this is more efficient than cashing in Bohemian connections, but it's definitely faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

In shuttered palace You can obrain 45 honey per action if You got 82th persuative level. Story called Corruption of Youth.

Answer (score 0):

50 Prisoner's Honey in Veilgarden if you're PoSI. It's the Unfinished Business - Doing the decent thing option.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the "Doing the Decent Thing" option, "Unfinished Business in Veilgarden" also has a useful storylet called "Take a Consignment of Old Props".  Requires 2 actions,and success is based on a 50-50 Luck roll, but if you succeed you get a variable quantity of honey that may be over 100.